# Return value for main function from a callback function

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

So i am using express routing to handle a get request. The get request will end up calling the a function that will handle sending an email. I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the function from continuing if one of the files fail to load.

routing logic:

```
app.get('/example',sendEmail,function(req,res){
    //Code that runs before calling my sendEmail function

    var results = sendEmail("example.com");

   // Check if sending the email was successful or threw an error.
});
```

email/EJS logic:

```
function sendEmail(emailAddress){
    var emailTEXT = ejs.renderFile('TEXT.ejs', function(err,file){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // break out of the sendEmail function by returning data
        } else {
            return file // Return this value to the variable and continue on with the function.
        }
    );
    var emailHTML = ejs.renderFile('HTML.ejs', function(err,file){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // break out of the sendEmail function by returning data
        } else {
            return file // Return this value to the variable and continue on with the function.
        }
    );

    // Code to send email with the HTML and TEXT version of the email.
}
```

I know I could return a blank string on error and check for that after each variable but there has to be an easier way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
function sendEmail(emailAddress){
    var emailTEXT = new EJS({url: 'TEXT.ejs'}).render(/* Some data */);
    var emailHTML = new EJS({url: 'HTML.ejs'}).render(/* Some data */);

    // Code to send email with the HTML and TEXT version of the email.
}
```

Comment: I am using the node version of ejs so i don't think this will work as 'EJS' wouldn't be defined. I have `var ejs = require('ejs');` inside the file as well. I'll try this tomorrow morning and see if it works.